# How to display the text value of an enum field?

Tags: django

I am using `django_enumfield`

My model looks like this:

```
class GenderValues(enum.Enum):
    NONE = 0
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 2
    BOTH = 3

class Gender(models.Model):
    gender = enum.EnumField(GenderValues, default=GenderValues.NONE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender
```

I have exposed this model in the admin area as follows:

```
admin.site.register(Gender)
```

I can then go to the admin area and add a gender.

Problem:

The gender appears as the number (e.g. 1 if I choose 'Male') instead of "MALE".

Note I have tried adding a label to GenderValues like this but it makes no difference:

```
labels = {
    MALE: 'Male',
}
```

Do you know how I can display "MALE" or "Male" in the admin area instead of 1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `_display()`

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_gender_display()
```

or

Use `list_display` (in admin)

```
class GenderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     list_display=['gender']

admin.site.register(Gender, GenderAdmin)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Do you mind me asking how you knew this? I'm finding it very hard to figure out this stuff without memorizing the django documentation...

Comment: You probably searched for EnumField or something. Using `choices` option is easier https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed search for EnumField... I can see the solution in the choices section now. Cheers!

Comment: Link to the actual method docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display